# Is there an elegant way to convert ISO 639-2 (3 letter) language codes to Java Locales?

Tags: java, localization, locale

E.g. eng, spa, ita, ger

I could iterate all locales and compare the codes, but I wonder whether there is a more elegant & performant way to achieve this....

Thanks a lot for any hints :)

Comment: The easiest way would be to use ISO 639-2 (2 letter) language codes instead, which is what the Locale class uses to begin with.

Comment: No that would definitely not be easy in my case... unfortunately...

Comment: Also, that should have said ISO 639-1, not -2.  Whoops.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easy way to convert the 3-letter to the 2-letter versions, but in a worse case scenario, you could create a Map of them, like so:

```
String[] languages = Locale.getISOLanguages();
Map<String, Locale> localeMap = new HashMap<String, Locale>(languages.length);
for (String language : languages) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    localeMap.put(locale.getISO3Language(), locale);
}
```

Now you can look up locales using things like `localeMap.get("eng")`;

Edit: Modified the way the map is created.  Now there should be one object per language.

Edit 2: It's been a while, but changed the code to use the actual length of the languages array when initializing the Map.

Comment: Thanks - I cannot say this is the answer I hoped for, but obviously there really is no better way :(

Comment: Not ideal, I know.  You'd think there'd be a built-in way of handling this...  Also, I modified the code to pre-allocate the map with 185 entries, as that's what (the windows version of) Java 6u11 has.

Comment: Yep, that is what I hoped - Java is weird sometimes.
Thanks for your input on this

Comment: It would e better to get languages first, then allocate localeMap based on languages' size.

Comment: Beware that java uses 639-2/T (or 639-3?) and not 639-2/B. So, German is `deu` and not `ger`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor `Locale(String language)`, where language is the 2 letter ISO-639-1 code. I think the easiest way to convert ISO-639-2 to ISO-639-1 would be to create `HashMap<String,String>` constant.

Comment: I know I could. Unfortunately 3 letter codes is what I get from the DB.

Comment: Hm would work, but is not quite elegant, I'd say...
Sometimes I wonder about Java... :-/

Comment: No it's not elegant. But using ISO-639-2 codes is rather uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Some modified code from my project, which has a similar requirement. We have our own historical timezone format so we can't use standard libraries.

```
public class MyProjectTimeZoneFactory  {

   private static Map timeZoneDb;

   /**
   * Set up our timezone id mappings; call this from any constructor
   * or static method that needs it.
   */
   private static void init() {
      if(null == TimeZoneDb) {
         timeZoneDb = new HashMap();   // Maybe a TreeMap would be more appropriate
         timeZoneDb.put("     ","GMT+00");
         timeZoneDb.put("EAD  ","GMT+10");
         timeZoneDb.put("JST  ","GMT+9");
         // etc.
       }
   }

   public static TimeZone getTimeZone(String id) 
                          throws CommandFormatException {
       init();

       TimeZone tz;
       if(timeZoneDb.containsKey(id)) {
           tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone((String)timeZoneDb.get(id));
       } else {
           throw new CommandFormatException("Invalid Timezone value");
       }

       return tz;
   }

 }
```

You could argue that it would be better to have the map in configuration rather than code - perhaps in a properties file. That may be true - but do remember the Pragmatic Programmers' rule 'Your not going to need it'.