# Android - Translating language codes

Tags: android, localization, translation

I get a response from a webservice that will return several language codes (ISO 639-2) as options. I now want to translate those into a human understandable word.
For example:

```
eng-> English
ger -> German
fre -> French
```

How would you translate those words. Should I be using the strings.xml? But how will I get the Resource ID of those words?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check this question, maybe it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674041/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-convert-iso-639-2-3-letter-language-codes-to-java-lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert 639-2 codes to 639-1 code using answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674041/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-convert-iso-639-2-3-letter-language-codes-to-java-lo)
and after you get a 2 letter code construct `Locale` object and use `getDisplayLanguage` method