# Is there way to convert 2 letter browser language code (Accept-Language) to 3 letter ISO639-2/B and ISO639-2/T without using java.util.Locale class?

Tags: java

I have following code in my Java application to convert 2 letter ISO639 language code to 3 letter ISO639 language code.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
String langCode = locale.getISO3Language();
System.out.println(langCode);
```

The above code will print out 'fra' only which is ISO639-2/T language code.

java.util.Locale supports only ISO639-2/T language code. Therefore, Locale cannot convert 2 letter language code to 3 letter ISO639-2/B language code. So, in my case, I cannot use java.util.Locale class.

Reference of ISO639-2/B and ISO639-2/T language codes: http://loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Is there any Java library which can handle both ISO639-2/T and ISO639-2/B language code, so I can get both 'fre' and 'fra' according to above code snippet?

Comment: I am not looking for the answer of the following discussion. It is different scenario than mine. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674041/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-convert-iso-639-2-3-letter-language-codes-to-java-l

Comment: There are only 22 'B' codes and it's unlikely they are going to be modified in any way, the 'T' code being preferred. That being the case, you could simply hardcode a 'T' to 'B' map for the 22 codes and replace the 'T' with the 'B' when such a substitution is available. While you can't extend Locale since it's final, it would be a pretty trivial method in a utility class.